# Creating array from MYSQL 'datetime' of years available

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, datetime, timestamp

I have looked around for a simple solution to this question but I can't seem to find one. What I have is a database full of timestamped date and would like to be able to pull out all the years and list them. For example I have the following data under 'date':

```
2014-11-19 19:58:07
2015-10-14 18:58:05
2014-09-05 04:28:02
2014-10-01 05:58:00
2017-01-20 18:48:00
2014-03-20 07:58:00
```

And would like to print only the following (if in database, with no repeats):

```
2014
2015
2017
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Edit: Sorry I'm pretty new to this I have "

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) FROM database;";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$numd=mysql_numrows($result);
echo $num;
```

and it prints:

```
3
```

but I would like it to print:

```
2014
2015
2017
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in PHP, you can convert the string to date using 'strtotime' and then get the year using 'date("Y", $time)'

```
$myDate = '2014-11-19 19:58:07';
$time = strtotime($myDate);
$year = date("Y", $time);
```

In this case, $year will be equal to 2014

**EDIT:** To store the years without having them to repeat you can create a new array and only add years to that array if they don't already exist

```
if( !in_array($year, $array) )
   #add the year to the array
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mysql `YEAR` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) FROM table_name;

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this so i would 'Select', as above, and then how would I print each year individually?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as myYear
FROM table
GROUP BY myYear
```